# How to add a column in the database using a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There's a form with name and data type input. On form submit, it should add another column to the table. It should execute the sql statement `ALTER TABLE users ADD name datatype;`. How can i accomplish this? I've tried this and it doesn't work.

```
def add_columns
    sql = "ALTER TABLE users ADD " + name + data_type;
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql);
end
```

Comment: Why do you need that? What do you try to achieve? How do you plan to work with that column later on in the application? Perhaps it is just me, but I cannot think of a reason why I would allow a user to change the schema of an application at runtime...

Comment: yeah, you have to be careful here not to allow SQL injection. Can a user hypothetically pass any string to your execute call? Then you are at risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you missed a space:

```
sql = ALTER TABLE users ADD #{name} #{data_type}"
```

and be aware of SQL injection while doing this

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add a column like this way, you should always use migration to populate your DB tables and columns